# Migrate WPA2-PSK keys between machines

Tags: windows, security, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I'm in the process of migrating my XP machine to Windows 7. Rather stupidly, I can't remember (nor find) my wireless keys. (They are also installed on a Vista machine if that makes anything easier).

Is there any way to extract and migrate the keys? Otherwise it may have to be a "reset the wireless access point" job... fortunately my wireless point and router are separate, so it won't be a huge job to reset - just irritating.

(For info, it is the same physical hardware, so the MAC filtering won't be an issue - and I know the SSID etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) should work.

Comment: Perfect. It turns out to be easier from Vista due to way that XP stores the data, but job done.